# Draw/delete (show/hide) specific lines on checkbox C# winForms Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, graphics

I created an app in C#, windows forms where I draw all my objects on panel. I created grid, lots of lines, rectangle, filled elipses etc...

I want to create checkbox where I can control which lines should be shown and when. For instance if checkbox is checked, show lines and if it is not checked, hide them or remove them from panel.

How to do this? I can only delete all objects from panel, not specific ones... How to iterate through program since there are no ID's?

Example how the objects are added.

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);

e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x1, y1, 10, 10);
```

Is there a way to group them somehow? I could rewrite whole code just with/without lines I want but since there is alot of code that's not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always redraw your panel.

```
private void chbShowLines_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Invalidate()
}

private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (chbShowLines.Checked)
    {
        // draw lines
    }

    // draw common parts
}
```

Comment: this helped me, sort of... but now i have to deal with constant flicker.. what is the efficient way to solve that?

Comment: You may try [double buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx) the form or control you're painting on to deal with the flicker.

Comment: tried it but it does not help... and i got mouseMove event which does not work during the flicker, after i wrote it like it's written above

Comment: This helped me reduce the flicker: `typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null, panel1, new object[] { true });`
But i have another problem now... my mouseMove event still does not work..
 `private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            label1.Text = "Current coordinates: " + point.ToString();
        }`